# Creating a constraints on two Column combination MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I am having a table with two Column name **Parent** and **Child**  having the data shown below.

```
|     Parent          |     Child        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      100            |      101         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I also have added the Unique Constraints on this two column and the command is as below:

```
ALTER TABLE Example ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Example UNIQUE (parent,child);
```

Now if i try insert **100** in Parent and  **101** in child, It is failing which is correct but i would like to stop the reverse insertion also 
Example: **101** in parent and **100** in child should fail also

Is there a way to do using sql or Procedure or any predefined sql command

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I am pretty sure that this is NOT possible without further coding. This is not how constraints are supposed to work! Anyways, a workaround would be to create a function which performs this check and to use this function in a check constraint... but this might reduce performance dramatically (depending on the number of records you insert).

Comment: I would suggest you create after insert trigger, i guess it should always be parent-child unidirectional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using computed columns.  That way, no additional functions or triggers need to be defined.

```
alter table example add min_id as (case when parentId < childId then parentId else childId end) persisted;

alter table example add max_id as (case when parentId < childId then childId else parentId end) persisted;
```

Now you can create a unique index/constraint:

```
alter table example add constraint unq_parent_child
    unique (min_id, max_id);
```

Comment: Performance of what?  Such an index only affects performance (negatively) when you insert values.  You already have at least one index on the table, so this is just another increment of overhead.  But . . . it should be better than using a user-defined function or trigger, which are normally a performance killers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with a function constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab1 (
    Parent INT
    ,Child INT
    )

INSERT INTO Tab1
  VALUES (100,101),(100,102)
GO

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnc_RestrictedInsert (@NewParent INT, @NewChild INT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT = 0;
    DECLARE @RetVal BIT = 1;

    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*)
      FROM Tab1
      WHERE (Parent = @NewParent AND Child = @NewChild)
        OR (Child = @NewParent AND Parent = @NewChild)

    SET @RetVal = CASE 
            WHEN @Count > 1
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END

    RETURN @RetVal;
END

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ALTER TABLE Tab1 WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Ins] CHECK (([dbo].[fnc_RestrictedInsert]([Parent], [Child]) = (1)))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO Tab1 VALUES (100,101)
INSERT INTO Tab1 VALUES (101,100)

INSERT INTO Tab1 VALUES (100,103)
```

Comment: I prompted out the performance in my first comment (under the OP) but didn't receive any feedback concerning amount of data etc. There fore the hint (in my comment) that this function might be a workaround, but that "this might reduce performance dramatically (depending on the number of records you insert)"